# Cannot navigate to other pages on the website after AJAX calls on Google Chrome

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, asp-net-mvc-1

I have a problem with my project that I have not found a solution for a long time.

One of the pages on the website has buttons that call for data from the server by AJAX calls, after I click on some of them I can not navigate to other pages on the website but I still manage to get data from the server by AJAX calls.

The code that executes the calls looks like this:

```
$('.get_data-button').click(function setData(id) {
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('.progress').show();
        },
        async: false,
        url: "/updates/readupdate?" + id,
        method: "GET",
        data: { id: id },
        success: function (data) {
            set_data = data;
            $(".updates").html(set_data);
            $('.progress').hide();
        },
        complete: function () {
            isComplete = true;
        }
    });
});
```

BTW, I have tested the issue in different browsers (Google Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Opera) and I experience this issue only with Google Chrome.

Has anyone experienced this problem and can suggest a solution?